# C# - Mail confirmation Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am developing an app that checks an Outlook mail account, finds all the attachments and then print them out. At this point, the mails analyzed are moved to another folder.

I have only one problem: sometimes, I receive some mails with reading confirmation. The app checks the attachment, and when it has to move the mail, it freezes. Then a popup appear in Outlook, about sending or not sending the reading confirmation.

Now, I want to make this programmatically, I always want to send a reading confirmation when it is requested.

I found a property (`ReadReceiptRequested`), set to true if there is a reading confirmation to send, but I don't know how to send it.

Here a piece of the code I use:

```
//I store all the emails in a List<Outlook.MailItem> named emails
Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
//Check if the mail has read confirmation
if (emails[right_index].ReadReceiptRequested)
{
    //How to send read confirmation?
}
//I read the mail, then I move it to another folder
emails[indice_scelto].UnRead = false;
emails[indice_scelto].Move(mapiNameSpace.Folders["New folder"]);
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show the code where you are reading the mails?

Comment: Of course, I need a bit of time to add some comment to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that on the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi) - call `IMessage::SetReadFlag()` - pass 0 to send read receipts or `SUPPRESS_RECEIPT` otherwise.

If [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes the [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`MarkRead` method that takes a `SuppressReceipt` Boolean parameter.

Comment: I'm checking this library, it is very interesting. When I will have news, I will let you know. Thank you for the moment.

Comment: I figure out how to use Redemption, it is a very powerful tool!
Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are using Redemption alongside your existing OOM code, create an instance of the RDOSession object, set its MAPIOBJECT property to Namespace.MAPIOBJECT, then call RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject or RDOSession.GetMessageFromID to reopen MailItem as RDOMail.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method. All you can is to set the [UnRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868556(v=office.15).aspx) property to false and [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866979(v=office.15).aspx) the item.

Then you can begin synchronizing a user's folders using the specified Send\Receive group using the [Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863925(v=office.15).aspx) method of the SyncObject class. The Namespace class provides the [SyncObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860705(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a SyncObjects collection containing all Send\Receive groups. For example:

```
 Public Sub Sync() 
  Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects 
  Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject 
  Dim i As Integer 
  Dim strPrompt As Integer 
  Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects 
  For i = 1 To sycs.Count 
   Set syc = sycs.Item(i) 
   strPrompt = MsgBox( _ 
   "Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo) 
   If strPrompt = vbYes Then 
    syc.Start 
   End If 
  Next 
 End Sub
```

I suppose then you can move the item wherever you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't have to save the mail. The only problem is to send the read confirmation.
By the way, I think I have found a solution, maybe it is not elegant, but I think it will work: when my app freezes, I will focus my Outlook application, so the user itself will choose if send or not the confirmation.

Comment: Did you try to use all the things I suggested in the code?

Comment: I'm honest, I don't use VB and I don't understand what your code do.

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kind of applications. So, I bielive you can see the properties and method used in the code.